# getgrgid bug when compiling in 32-bit on Redhat 7?

Tags: c++, redhat, 32-bit

I've been looking at this bug for the past couple of days now and can't seem to find anything about it online, I noticed that when I try to use getgrgid and compile the program with a 32-bit flag the function does not return any group. But it is still getting the group id correctly.
Consider the following program:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <grp.h>
int main()
{
    struct group* result = getgrgid(getgid());
    std::cout << result->gr_name << std::endl;
}
```

When compiled with `g++ test.cpp -m32 -o test`, the process will crash with `segmentation fault (core dumped)` (due to a null pointer being returned) being the error message. However when compiled with `g++ test.cpp -m64 -o test` the correct output is shown when the program is run. I am interested in knowing why this function returns the correct value when compiled with 64-bit and returns NULL when compiling with 32-bit.
The errno is still 0 after the function is called.

My questions are:

Why does it not work on 32-bit?

Is it some configuration issue?

Has anyone seen this before?

Is there a workaround besides parsing through ps calls?

Should I report this as a bug?

Comment: I’d suggest using gdb to find which line is causing the crash. Is it possible that the group wasn’t found, hence ->gr_name is null?

Comment: The crash is 100% being caused by ```std::cout << result->gr_name << std::endl;``` due to the return of getgrgid being NULL. I'm more focused on why it returns NULL when compiled with -m32 but it returns the correct value when compiled with -m64.

Comment: I should also note that the value of errno is 0 after the call.

Comment: This is a valuable information worth including in the posting. For further debugging, it is helpful to know the gid, as well as where 64bit environment finds the group definition. Does it come from /etc/group? Maybe it’s provided by a plugin that’s not installed for 32bit environment.

Comment: Segfault is result of fact you are not checking for errors. `getgrgid` can return `NULL`: https://linux.die.net/man/3/getgrgid so you are de-referencing nullptr: [I can reproduce this on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/YxrT3r1oc). Now you have to just find explanation why `null` is returned. [Version with error handling](https://godbolt.org/z/TcaazanWz).

Comment: That's it! I've been working under the assumption that the two functions would pull from the same source. I checked out /etc/group and found that the group I am trying to find is not there, but trying a group defined in the file does work. It is likely as you said, there's probably a plugin for the 64-bit environment but not the 32-bit one, as we use PAM to communicate to an LDAP server for authentication. the 64-bit version is likely pulling it's information from there.

Comment: Funny how the function is working exactly as intended, but my lack of understanding of how groups work is what was holding me back.

Answer (score 0):

As per Nick Zavaritsky's comment, I verified that groups were being pulled from 2 different sources. The 32-bit version is pulling from /etc/group while the 64-bit version is likely pulling from our LDAP server.